# What's the maximum single withdrawal amount from an ANZ bank ATM in Laos?

Tags: fees, withdrawal, atm

I'm travelling in Laos and it's time to withdraw some money.

Now because all the fees between my home bank, the local bank, the local country, sub optimal spread for the currency conversion, and being charged a percentage (3% from what I can find so far) I like to withdraw enough money to last a couple of weeks each time I go to the ATM.

I have found via Googling that some ATMs have a limit of 1,000,000 Laotian Kip (LAK) but it looks like that's not necessarily the same across all banks. [The ANZ Laos website](http://www.anz.com.au/laos/en/Personal/) doesn't seem to have this information.

I'll be using ANZ ATMs since I'll be withdrawing from an Australian ANZ account and there's a chance the fees might be lower and the service might be better if I have any problems.

Now one million Kip is only $135 AUD so I'm hoping to be able to withdraw more. $300 AUD would be ideal but I'd like to know the maximum please.

(If this question does not belong here, please migrate it to travel.SE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This afternoon I used an ANZ ATM inside the Branch on Lane Xang Avenue. The ATM tells you the maximum.

- You can withdraw up to 2,000,000 `LAK` per withdrawal. <sup>($254 `USD`, €188 `EUR`)</sup>
- It must be a multiple of 50,000 `LAK`. <sup>($6.35 `USD`, €4.70 `EUR`)</sup>

Pro tip: If the wad of bills is too thick you can change it at the teller to bills of 100,000 kip each to slim it down a little.

I read on a forum that most other banks' ATMs in Laos have a maximum of 1,000,000 `LAK` but that ANZ's fees are a bit higher than the other ATMs.